# Where can I get numerical data for the PAR (photosynthetically active radiation) curve?

Tags: photosynthesis, literature, light

I'm trying to do some rough figuring to calculating efficiencies of various light sources for growing plants.  I'm hampered, however, by the lack of a curve to multiply by the spectrum of light sources to determine the amount of photosynthetically active radiation that a typical plant will absorb and use.

I can find curves like below all over, but I can't get numerical data in the form of tables. Is there some source from where I can get such data?

[image: PAR curve]

Comment: plantphysiol.org/content/early/2013/06/28/… is a starting point. He cites a paper of Mcree which may have what you're looking for (pay wall for me). Evans says that photosynthesis for 400-700nm drops off quickly as function of temperature. Red/blue encourage flowering/growth, a gardening truism which may be based on Mcree's paper.

Comment: @daniel your link was cut off

Comment: This is it---http://www.plantphysiol.org/content/early/2013/06/28/pp.113.219006.full.pdf--except for the standard characters at the beginning ending with the three w's.

Comment: @daniel a safer way to provide links in comments is using markdown, e.g. `[Google](http://www.google.com/)` = [Google](http://www.google.com/).  The second link you pasted has a "--except" appended on the end that I had to manually remove.

Comment: @NickT sorry for the late comment but what do you mean here, by "numerical"

Comment: @WYSIWYG as in a table (spreadsheet, etc) of values with the wavelength then the PAR value for each one.

Comment: @NickT Is the table not available from the source of this image?

Comment: @NickT I think you should try one of the programs that can be used to extract numerical information from images. I never used one. There is another trick that you can try using Inkscape: import your image → crop to desired region → trace path from the image → Remove unnecessary points → simplify the path → add more nodes if you want to get more datapoints (select all nodes and click add node) → Select all → resize document to selection → save as SVG. SVG doesn't store co-ordinates but you can obtain them using parsers or other tricks.

Comment: To know how to extract co-ordinates from SVG see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118118/extracting-coordinates-of-a-path-from-an-svg-file) and [here](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=8826). Since you know the X/Y scale from image you can get the original data points.

Comment: [This](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168192395022457) is one paper where you can get that data.

Comment: @WYSIWYG that paper just has insolation data over the year, not the spectrum of what PAR is.

Comment: @NickT Did you try obtaining the numerical data from this curve?